# Access to UIBinder field values by field names passed as String?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I want to access field values rendered by UIBinder by their names passed as String value

Is there any way to access data stored in ui field like

**PersonViewImpl.ui.xml**

```
<g:TextBox ui:field="lastName"/>
```

**PersonViewImpl.java**

```
@UIField
String lastName
public Object fieldByName(String fieldName) {
    ....
    return value;
}
```

**PersonActivity.java**

```
PersonView view;
String ln = (String)view.fieldByName("lastName");
```

Any solutions? Thnx in advice

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend to use this pattern to dynamically access widgets. It's not really clean code and can easily break.
If you have a lot of fields you want to bind I would recommend to use [Editors](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors).

If you still want to access widgets this, you have 2 choices:

1. Create a `HashMap` containing all your `TextBox`es (or whatever fields you want to access) and use the fieldname as a key. You can create a helper function to retrieve the values based on the key. However you have to populate your `HashMap` yourself.
2. If you have all your widgets inside a container widgets (i.e. `FlowPanel`) you can traverse through the list of widgets of the container widget and retrieve them. You will probably set the id to the fieldname to identify them.

Comment: Thanks Ümit for quick response. Editors approach is nice. But I didn't want to use beans for DTO. My thought was around using HashMap-style DTO produced by HQL select new Map(...) expression. Than I need to bind this data to widgets and during edititng compose DTO with updated field for sending back to server